# sed find and replace for only specific number of occurrences

Tags: linux, perl, sed

I have the following problem.

I have a file with sequence and I want to find a specific pattern and replace it with another pattern, but only for a specific number of times.

eg:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
```

I want to find "DEFGHI" and replace it with "ABCDEF" for only 3 times.

```
sed -i 's/DEFGHI/ABCDEF/g' /home/user/test.txt
```

I don't want to replace globally; instead I want to replace only 3 times.

Comment: Sorry. i want to replace with another patten. eg : DEFGHI with ABCDEF

Comment: This is non-trivial. Can the pattern occur more than once per line?

Comment: @toolic You're assuming there is exactly one match in every line (i.e. it'll break if it's more or less).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the task description is unclear and OP is not responding to requests for clarification. (In particular: Can the pattern appear more than once in a single line? Can the pattern appear less than once in a line (that is, are there lines that don't match at all)?)

Comment: `perl -pi -e's/DEFGHI/ABCDEF/ and $i++ if $i<3' /home/user/test.txt`.  Extremely difficult to do with sed.

Comment: sorry for not clear. pattern will be only once and for some lines the pattern will not match.. thanks for your hints

Answer (score 2):

This replaces the given pattern three times, whichever way they're distributed over lines

```
perl -0777 -pe'$i += s/DEF/xxx/ while $i < 3' < data.txt  > out.txt
```

It assumes that the pattern is not broken over lines. It makes passes over the string, searching from the beginning each time. This comes with a caveat explained below and is ineffcient but it is simple.

If the replacement itself recreates the pattern when combined with the surrounding text, this will also be replaced in the next pass. Such a replacement would have to contain parts of the pattern itself and in a specific way. Still, if this is a concern let me know.

Handling of possible overlapping patterns is not specified in the problem. If there are any this solution will replace the first so in the next pass the overlapping one will have been gone.

Comment: The (deleted) answer by @sidyll has the right idea and was helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using bash and GNU sed like this:

```
sed -z -i "$(echo s/DEFGHI/ABCDEF/{3..1}\;)" yourfile
```

- The `{3..1}` results in the the `s` part repeated three time with flag 3 to 1. Each `s` command replaces only the third, second and first occurence. The inverted order is necessary, so that the counting and replacing do not mix up.
- `-z` takes all the input lines at once, thus the counting is not per line but per file.

For your reference, here is what the command substitution around the echo produces:

```
echo s/DEFGHI/ABCDEF/{3..1}\;
> s/DEFGHI/ABCDEF/3; s/DEFGHI/ABCDEF/2; s/DEFGHI/ABCDEF/1;
```

Comment: @SLePort You are right. I inverted the sequence. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the sed+shell combo which works well for arbitrary values other than 3.  This "brace expansion" though, to be clear... bash?  So it's GNU sed+bash and bashlike shells.

Comment: "This can be done using bash *Brace Expansion* and GNU sed like this:" ...

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the first occurrence found three times:

```
sed -i '0,/DEFGHI/s//ABCDEF/;0,/DEFGHI/s//ABCDEF/;0,/DEFGHI/s//ABCDEF/' file
```

output:

```
ABCABCDEFJKLMN
ABCABCDEFJKLMN
ABCABCDEFJKLMN
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
```